# Execute command then parallelize other commands after completion

Tags: bash, parallel-computing

I'm looking for a single inline command to execute `/bin/first` and then when it completes execute the following `/bin/p1`, `/bin/p2`, `/bin/p3` in parallel after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start and run commands in the background from a shell script by appending a <kbd>&</kbd> to the command, they  will run almost completely in parallel because the script won't need to wait until the command completes before executing the next line in the script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
/bin/first
/bin/p1 &
/bin/p2 &
/bin/p3
```

**Note:** When the script completes p1 and p2 may still be running in the background!

To alleviate that your script becomes slightly more complex as you'll need to capture the PID's and `wait` for them:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
/bin/first
/bin/p1 &
PID1=$!
/bin/p2 & 
PID2=$!
/bin/p3 & 
PID3=$!  
for PIDS in $PID1 $PID2 $PID3 ;
do
  wait $PIDS
done
```

That for loop is only needed if you want to do some error handling and check the exit code of the programs you executed in parallel. Otherwise a simple `wait` without any arguments will also wait for all child processes to terminate.

Comment: there a way to have the script only complete once all `p1`, `p2`, `p3` are complete?

Comment: capture the PID's and use the bash built-in function `wait` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make sure the output does not mix:

```
/bin/first
parallel ::: /bin/p1 /bin/p2 /bin/p3
```